# How to control an led from Thingspeak server using SIM900A and Arduino?

Tags: arduino, sim900

I am trying to control a LED from Thingspeak server by using the GSM module.
The data received is successfully being printed on serial monitor(which is '1' as last updated) but when I am trying to assign that data to a variable so as to control the inbuilt LED of Arduino, nothing happens.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial SIM900A(10, 11);
void setup()
{
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
    ;
  Serial.println("Arduino is ready");
  SIM900A.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("SIM900A started at 9600");
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("Setup Complete");
}

void loop()
{
  SIM900A.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  ShowSerialData();

  SIM900A.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  SIM900A.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
  delay(2000);
  ShowSerialData();

  SIM900A.println("AT+CGATT=1");
  delay(5000);

  SIM900A.println("AT+CSTT=\"INTERNET\",\"\",\"\"");
  delay(4000);

  SIM900A.println("AT+CIICR");
  delay(3000);
  ShowSerialData();

  SIM900A.println("AT+CIFSR");
  delay(5000);
  ShowSerialData();

  SIM900A.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"184.106.153.149\",\"80\"");
  delay(4000);
  ShowSerialData();

  SIM900A.println("AT+CIPSEND");
  delay(4000);

  SIM900A.print("GET /channels/798173/fields/1/last");
  SIM900A.print("\r\n\x1A");
  ShowSerialData();

  char led = SIM900A.read();
  Serial.print(led);

  if (led == '1')
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  }

  else if (led == '0')
  {
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  }

  delay(8000);
}

void ShowSerialData()
{
  while (SIM900A.available() != 0)
    Serial.print(char(SIM900A.read()));
}
```

Last portion of the output from the serial monitor:

```
CONNECT OK
AT+CIPSEND

> ⸮GET /channels/798173/fields/1/last

SEND OK
1
```

Comment: You are receiving the data in variable led ?

Comment: No, the output i.e. '1' is being printed from ShowSerialData(). If I remove it, no data is printed by Serial.print(led).

Comment: Ok, try commenting the ShowSerialData() function just before this ```char led = SIM900A.read();```

Comment: AT+CIPSEND

> GET /channels/798173/fields/1/last

SEND OK

Comment: This is the new output. (no data is printed)

Comment: Replace ```char led = SIM900A.read();``` with ```char led = char(SIM900A.read());```, Does it make any difference ? Make sure ```ShowSerialData()``` in the previous line is commented

Comment: Same problem persists.

Comment: Is this string "SEND OK 1" being printed by ShowSerialData() ? Also does it include the data you want to receive ?

Comment: No just '1' is printed by ShowSerialData() which is the data being received.

Comment: Please update the question with the entire output if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Saurabh P Bhandari, you cannot read the same data from the serial twice, thus you'd need to read the data in a variable in the first place if you wish to use it.

```
String getSerialData(){
      String buffer="";
      while (SIM900A.available() ){
        char c = SIM900A.read();
        buffer+=c;    
      }
      return buffer;
     }
```

Then you can use `String led = getSerialData()` to populate `led` with the buffer.
Here, you need to beware that the function `getSerialData` would return anything present on the buffer and would look something like:

```
GET /channels/798173/fields/1/last
SEND

HTTP RESPONSE
```

It appears that you're only interested in `HTTP RESPONSE`, thus you can update your conditionals to be

```
if(led.endsWith("1"))
...
else if(led.endsWith("0"))
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I made required changes in the code as suggested by you and now it is working perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have understood so far, in this snippet

```
SIM900A.print("GET /channels/798173/fields/1/last");  
SIM900A.print("\r\n\x1A");
ShowSerialData();
```

`ShowSerialData()` is printing the output which is '1'. Then immediately your are reading data into the variable `led`. Since, the actual data received is being printed already from `ShowSerialData()`, the next time you call `SIM900A.read()` will return either nothing or next set of data being sent by your module.

Answer (score 1):

You are likely getting rate limited because you are hitting ThingSpeak servers too frequently. You can only update a channel once every 15s with a free account. Obviously, it makes no sense to ask for a value faster than it can be updated, i.e., once every 15s with a free account.

Consider putting some required delays in your code to ensure your device is not blacklisted for abuse of terms.